# Linking error wihle crosscompiling iothub sdk

Tags: c, azure, cmake, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I'm trying to crosscompile the azure iothub sdk, written in C, for an ARM gateway.
This gateway is provided with its crosscompiler.

I need iothub's libraries and includes in order to develop on the gateway.
I've downloaded and crosscompiled zlib, curl, openssl and libuuid for thar ARM device without problems.
Currently I'm stuck at the linking phase of the crosscompilation.
In order to compile the sdk Cmake is used, so I've provided a cusom toolchain file to setup paths and directories to my development environment.

This is the system configuration:

- OS: Linux 2.6.36
- Architecture: ARM9
- Azure IoTHub SDK Version: 2017-11-03

**toolchain file (toolchain.cmake)**:

```
INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CC_FLAGS} -L/opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib -ldl -lcrypto -lssl")
#set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "--std=c99 ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -L/opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib -ldl -lcrypto -lssl")
set(CXX_FLAG_CXX11 "--std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi)

#OpenSSL path
set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/ssl)
set(OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
#set(OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/armv4t/usr/lib/libcrypt.a)
set(OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/libssl.a)
set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/include)

#libcurl path
set(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/include/curl)
set(CURL_LIBRARY /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/libcurl.a)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

To compile the sdk I run following commands inside /sdk/directory/cmake/ :

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/
cmake --build .
```

First command returns to me this output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.4.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.4.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for include file stdint.h
-- Looking for include file stdint.h - found
-- Looking for include file stdbool.h
-- Looking for include file stdbool.h - found
-- target architecture: ARM
-- Found OpenSSL: /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (found version "1.0.2m")
-- Cross compiling not using pkg-config
-- Found CURL: /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/libcurl.a
-- Found CURL: /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/libcurl.a
-- target architecture: ARM
-- target architecture: ARM
-- target architecture: ARM
-- iothub architecture: ARM
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ubuntu/azure-iot-sdk-c/cmake
```

I'm getting problems with the secon one which got an error at the 20% of the process while linking files, this the output:

```
[ 19%] Built target aziotsharedutil
Scanning dependencies of target iot_c_utility
[ 20%] Building C object c-utility/samples/iot_c_utility/CMakeFiles/iot_c_utility.dir/iot_c_utility.c.o
[ 20%] Linking C executable iot_c_utility
../../libaziotsharedutil.a(tlsio_openssl.c.o): In function log_ERR_get_error': tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1198): undefined reference toERR_get_error'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x11d4): undefined reference to ERR_error_string' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1224): undefined reference toERR_get_error'
../../libaziotsharedutil.a(tlsio_openssl.c.o): In function openssl_dynamic_locks_uninstall': tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1450): undefined reference toCRYPTO_set_dynlock_create_callback'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1458): undefined reference to CRYPTO_set_dynlock_lock_callback' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1460): undefined reference toCRYPTO_set_dynlock_destroy_callback'
../../libaziotsharedutil.a(tlsio_openssl.c.o): In function openssl_dynamic_locks_install': tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1484): undefined reference toCRYPTO_set_dynlock_destroy_callback'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1494): undefined reference to CRYPTO_set_dynlock_lock_callback' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x14a4): undefined reference toCRYPTO_set_dynlock_create_callback'
../../libaziotsharedutil.a(tlsio_openssl.c.o): In function openssl_static_locks_lock_unlock_cb': tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x14ec): undefined reference toCRYPTO_num_locks'
../../libaziotsharedutil.a(tlsio_openssl.c.o): In function openssl_static_locks_uninstall': tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x15f4): undefined reference toCRYPTO_set_locking_callback'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1658): undefined reference to CRYPTO_num_locks' ../../libaziotsharedutil.a(tlsio_openssl.c.o): In functionopenssl_static_locks_install':
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1790): undefined reference to CRYPTO_num_locks' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x18ec): undefined reference toCRYPTO_num_locks'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1908): undefined reference to CRYPTO_num_locks' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1980): undefined reference toCRYPTO_set_locking_callback'
../../libaziotsharedutil.a(tlsio_openssl.c.o): In function write_outgoing_bytes': tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1b60): undefined reference toBIO_ctrl_pending'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1c18): undefined reference to BIO_read' ../../libaziotsharedutil.a(tlsio_openssl.c.o): In functionsend_handshake_bytes':
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1d38): undefined reference to ERR_clear_error' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1d48): undefined reference toSSL_do_handshake'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1d70): undefined reference to SSL_get_error' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1db8): undefined reference toERR_get_error'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x1dc8): undefined reference to ERR_error_string' ../../libaziotsharedutil.a(tlsio_openssl.c.o): In functiondecode_ssl_received_bytes':
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x21d0): undefined reference to SSL_read' ../../libaziotsharedutil.a(tlsio_openssl.c.o): In functionon_underlying_io_bytes_received':
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x22e8): undefined reference to BIO_write' ../../libaziotsharedutil.a(tlsio_openssl.c.o): In functionclose_openssl_instance':
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x241c): undefined reference to SSL_free' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2448): undefined reference toSSL_CTX_free'
../../libaziotsharedutil.a(tlsio_openssl.c.o): In function add_certificate_to_store': tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x249c): undefined reference toSSL_CTX_get_cert_store'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x24d0): undefined reference to BIO_s_mem' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2508): undefined reference toBIO_new'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2544): undefined reference to BIO_puts' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x25b4): undefined reference toX509_STORE_add_cert'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x25c8): undefined reference to X509_free' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x25e4): undefined reference toX509_free'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2600): undefined reference to PEM_read_bio_X509' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x263c): undefined reference toBIO_free'
../../libaziotsharedutil.a(tlsio_openssl.c.o): In function create_openssl_instance': tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x26b0): undefined reference toTLSv1_2_method'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x26d0): undefined reference to TLSv1_1_method' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x26e0): undefined reference toTLSv1_method'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x26f0): undefined reference to SSL_CTX_new' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2758): undefined reference toSSL_CTX_free'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x27e4): undefined reference to SSL_CTX_free' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2870): undefined reference toSSL_CTX_free'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2904): undefined reference to SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2908): undefined reference toBIO_s_mem'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2914): undefined reference to BIO_new' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2940): undefined reference toSSL_CTX_free'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x296c): undefined reference to BIO_s_mem' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2978): undefined reference toBIO_new'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x29a4): undefined reference to BIO_free' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x29b4): undefined reference toSSL_CTX_free'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x29f8): undefined reference to BIO_ctrl' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2a20): undefined reference toBIO_ctrl'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2a3c): undefined reference to BIO_free' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2a4c): undefined reference toBIO_free'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2a5c): undefined reference to SSL_CTX_free' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2ae0): undefined reference toSSL_CTX_set_verify'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2af0): undefined reference to SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2b60): undefined reference toSSL_new'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2b8c): undefined reference to BIO_free' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2b9c): undefined reference toBIO_free'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2bac): undefined reference to SSL_CTX_free' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2bfc): undefined reference toSSL_set_bio'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2c0c): undefined reference to SSL_set_connect_state' ../../libaziotsharedutil.a(tlsio_openssl.c.o): In functiontlsio_openssl_init':
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2c88): undefined reference to SSL_library_init' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2c8c): undefined reference toSSL_load_error_strings'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2c90): undefined reference to ERR_load_BIO_strings' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2c94): undefined reference toOPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf'
../../libaziotsharedutil.a(tlsio_openssl.c.o): In function tlsio_openssl_deinit': tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2d40): undefined reference toFIPS_mode_set'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2d48): undefined reference to CRYPTO_set_locking_callback' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2d50): undefined reference toCRYPTO_set_id_callback'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2d54): undefined reference to ERR_free_strings' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2d58): undefined reference toEVP_cleanup'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2d60): undefined reference to ERR_remove_thread_state' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2d64): undefined reference toSSL_COMP_free_compression_methods'
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x2d68): undefined reference to CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data' ../../libaziotsharedutil.a(tlsio_openssl.c.o): In functiontlsio_openssl_send':
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x38e4): undefined reference to SSL_write' ../../libaziotsharedutil.a(tlsio_openssl.c.o): In functiontlsio_openssl_setoption':
tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x423c): undefined reference to SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback' tlsio_openssl.c:(.text+0x42ac): undefined reference toSSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback'
../../libaziotsharedutil.a(x509_openssl.c.o): In function log_ERR_get_error': x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x80): undefined reference toERR_get_error'
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to ERR_error_string' x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x10c): undefined reference toERR_get_error'
../../libaziotsharedutil.a(x509_openssl.c.o): In function load_certificate_chain': x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x170): undefined reference toBIO_new_mem_buf'
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x1b4): undefined reference to PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX' x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x1f0): undefined reference toSSL_CTX_use_certificate'
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x250): undefined reference to sk_pop_free' x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x274): undefined reference toSSL_CTX_ctrl'
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x288): undefined reference to X509_free' x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x2ac): undefined reference toPEM_read_bio_X509'
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x2d0): undefined reference to ERR_peek_last_error' x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x300): undefined reference toERR_clear_error'
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x31c): undefined reference to X509_free' x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x324): undefined reference toBIO_free'
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x344): undefined reference to X509_free' ../../libaziotsharedutil.a(x509_openssl.c.o): In functionload_alias_key_cert':
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x374): undefined reference to BIO_new_mem_buf' x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x3b8): undefined reference toPEM_read_bio_PrivateKey'
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x3f4): undefined reference to SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey' x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x470): undefined reference toEVP_PKEY_free'
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x478): undefined reference to BIO_free' ../../libaziotsharedutil.a(x509_openssl.c.o): In functionload_private_key_RSA':
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x4c8): undefined reference to BIO_new_mem_buf' x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x50c): undefined reference toPEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey'
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x548): undefined reference to SSL_CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey' x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x580): undefined reference toRSA_free'
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0x588): undefined reference to BIO_free' ../../libaziotsharedutil.a(x509_openssl.c.o): In functionx509_openssl_add_certificates':
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0xa1c): undefined reference to SSL_CTX_get_cert_store' x509_openssl.c:(.text+0xa50): undefined reference toBIO_s_mem'
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0xa88): undefined reference to BIO_new' x509_openssl.c:(.text+0xac4): undefined reference toBIO_puts'
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0xb1c): undefined reference to X509_STORE_add_cert' x509_openssl.c:(.text+0xb2c): undefined reference toERR_peek_error'
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0xb60): undefined reference to X509_free' x509_openssl.c:(.text+0xb6c): undefined reference toX509_free'
x509_openssl.c:(.text+0xb88): undefined reference to PEM_read_bio_X509' x509_openssl.c:(.text+0xbc4): undefined reference toBIO_free'
../../libaziotsharedutil.a(crt_abstractions.c.o): In function splitFloatString': crt_abstractions.c:(.text+0x10b8): undefined reference topow'
crt_abstractions.c:(.text+0x1150): undefined reference to pow' ../../libaziotsharedutil.a(crt_abstractions.c.o): In functionstrtof_s':
crt_abstractions.c:(.text+0x127c): undefined reference to pow' ../../libaziotsharedutil.a(crt_abstractions.c.o): In functionstrtold_s':
crt_abstractions.c:(.text+0x158c): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
c-utility/samples/iot_c_utility/CMakeFiles/iot_c_utility.dir/build.make:95: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "c-utility/samples/iot_c_utility/iot_c_utility" non riuscito
make[2]: *** [c-utility/samples/iot_c_utility/iot_c_utility] Errore 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1056: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "c-utility/samples/iot_c_utility/CMakeFiles/iot_c_utility.dir/all" non riuscito
make[1]: *** [c-utility/samples/iot_c_utility/CMakeFiles/iot_c_utility.dir/all] Errore 2
Makefile:140: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "all" non riuscito
make: *** [all] Errore 2
```

I'm trying to figure out what library or link directive I'm missing because I think I'm not referencing a compiled library in the correct way, but I wasn't able to find the solution yet.
Is there someone who already solved a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VERBOSE=1 to get the output from the linker.

It looks like you are missing to link against libssl and libcrypto

Comment: I was linking the wrong library file, the verbose option has worked